# Can't render a rails partial inside CoffeScript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I try something like this on CoffeScript file located the assets pipeline.

```
<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "shared/mypartial")%>
```

But I get the following error

```
throw Error("NoMethodError: undefined method `render' for #<#    <Class:0x007fb68f801a40>:0x007fb68d3c3fe8>\n  (in /Users/user/Sites/app/app/assets/javascripts/application/app.js.coffee.erb)")
```

Any idea why is not getting the render method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coffeescript files aren't processed within the context of a request, therefore you won't be able to access the render method.